# Stable-sorting all even numbers before odd numbers in a linked list

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, linked-list, time-limit-exceeded, c++14

> Given a Linked List of integers, write a function to modify the linked
>   list such that all **even numbers appear before all the odd numbers in
>   the modified linked list.** Also, keep the **order** of even and odd
>   numbers **same.** - (from geeksforgeeks: [Segregate even and odd nodes in a Linked List](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segregate-even-and-odd-elements-in-a-linked-list/))
>
> Example:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 3
> 7
> 17 15 8 9 2 4 6
> 4
> 1 3 5 7
> 7
> 8 12 10 5 4 1 6
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 8 2 4 6 17 15 9
> 1 3 5 7
> 8 12 10 4 6 5 1
> ```

My Approach: get pointer to the last node of list. And then traverse the list starting from the head node and move the odd valued nodes from their current position to end of the list.Also if all the node's data is even or odd then list remains unmodified so first I check if this is the case then I simply return(**len** is total number of nodes & **count** is total number of even data nodes).

I am getting right answer on an IDE, but on other IDE where the code needs to be submitted, it's showing **time limit exceeded**.

How do I optimize my code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int flag=0;
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
void addkey(struct Node** head_ref,int key)
{struct Node* temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
temp->next=NULL;
temp->data=key;
    if(*head_ref==NULL)
    {
      *head_ref=temp;  
    }
    else
    {
        struct Node* ptr=*head_ref;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
        {
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next=temp;
    }
}
void segregate(struct Node**head_ref)
{   int len=0,count=0;
    struct Node* ptr1=*head_ref;
    struct Node* ptr2=*head_ref;
    struct Node* prev=NULL;
    while(ptr2->next!=NULL)
    {
        if((ptr2->data)%2==0) count++;  
        ptr2=ptr2->next;
        len++;
    }
    if(ptr2->data%2==0)  count++;
    if(count==len+1||count==0)  return;
    struct Node* ptr5=ptr2;
    while(ptr1!=ptr5->next)
    {
        if((ptr1->data%2)==0)
        { if(flag==0) {
        *head_ref=ptr1;
        flag=1;}
            prev=ptr1;
            ptr1=ptr1->next;
        }
        else
        {
          if(prev!=NULL)  prev->next=ptr1->next;
            ptr2->next=ptr1;
            ptr2=ptr2->next;
            ptr1=ptr1->next;
            ptr2->next=NULL;
        }
    }
}
void printlist(struct Node* head)
{
    if(head==NULL) return;
    else
    {
        while(head!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<head->data<<" ";
            head=head->next;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    int T ;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        struct Node* head=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        head=NULL;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {int key;
         cin>>key;
         addkey(&head,key);
        }
        segregate(&head);
        printlist(head);cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? What if you could do the task better without using linked lists?

Comment: @200_success No not a homework question..you can suggest without using linked list too.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to accelerate your code is to defenestrate it (9.82 m/s2) and use the correct algorithm.

You don't need to do anything fancy. Just go through the list once, print all the even numbers, go through once more and print the odd ones.

Comment: Do you think that `std::stable_partition` will be slower? Though your solution is definitely the easiest.

Comment: In the general case I think two linear scans will be faster except when the input is already properly sorted. Of course I'd need to measure to be sure. The big time consumer would be branch mispredictions whenever determining if to print or not in the linear scans. But regardless it's not possible to do better than O(n).

Comment: It got me wondering if there are any practical usages for stable (or not) partition, may be when in-placeness is required? There are very few cases when a value is swappable and not movable. By the way, nice joke, though deletion of text or files do not abide gravity, if you didn't mean to throw away the computer too :)

Comment: `std::stable_sort` has provisions for dealing with large arrays and producing an output array, my solution only prints the answer without actually constructing it in memory. It's a metaphorical defenestration :)

Comment: @EmilyL. But actual question is to modify the linked list otherwise there's no meaning in question, I can solve it using array also then.I don't want to solve any question just for the sake of getting it submitted, want to learn also.So please suggest something else:)

Comment: @Hanoi Change "print" into append to output array :)

Comment: @EmilyL. Can you please suggest something using Linked list:)

Comment: @Hanoi, I posted my answer. It doesn't use linked list, but it gives some pointers about where to search for to improve.

Comment: @Hanoi to be honest the original problem isn't great for learning as it encourages coming up with an ad-hoc solution that probably isn't great instead of studying the typical stable partition algorithms.

Comment: @Hanoi make a linked list of the input, iterate over it once, copy even numbers into a new linked list, iterate over the lined list once more and copy the odd numbers into the output linkde list, print. The solution doesn't change depending on which implementation of list you use in this case :)

Comment: @EmilyL. Yeah, you are right.

Comment: @Hanoi the question as formulated is basically "I have this easy problem I want to solve but you must do it in the most convoluted manner possible and it won't matter for the result" :)

Answer (score 4):

### Code Review (or its absence)

There are way too many problems to talk about. This is definitely not idiomatic C++14, let alone C++98. Please grab a book from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). The algorithm you are searching for though is called "stable partition".

### Better solution

[Emily's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/36120/emily-l) [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/209722/revisions) is already great. Use it if you need to just solve the problem.

### Alternative solution

Here is the C++14 solution with standard library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using in_iterator = std::istream_iterator<int>;
using out_iterator = std::ostream_iterator<int>;

void iteration(int count) {
    std::vector<int> values(count);
    std::copy_n(in_iterator{std::cin}, count, 
                values.begin());

    std::stable_partition(values.begin(), values.end(), 
                          [](auto x) {return x % 2 == 0;});

    std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), 
              out_iterator{std::cout, " "});
}

int main() {   
    int test_count = 0;
    std::cin >> test_count;
    for (; test_count >= 0; --test_count) {
        int value_count = 0;
        std::cin >> value_count;
        iteration(value_count);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

I believe everything happening in `main()` is fairly obvious.

```
std::vector<int> values(count);
std::copy_n(in_iterator{std::cin}, count, 
            values.begin());
```

Those two lines initialize the `values` vector, by first creating the vector to hold `count` elements, then copying `count` elements from `std::cin` into `values`.

The next statement is just invocation of the algorithm from standard library.

The last line of the `iteration` function just copies the whole of the `values` into the `std::cout` stream.

Solution with linked list will be the same, just way more lengthier. One can also reimplement the stable partition too, if you feel like it.

Comment: Solution with linked lists: `sed -i 's/vector/list/g' solution.cpp` :D

Comment: @EmilyL., ikr, I would choose that solution any day of the week over reimplementing linked list

Answer (score 4):

#### Bug: Infinite loop

If your program runs on a list that ends in an odd number, it will run forever in an infinite loop.  For example, try this input:

```
1
3
1 2 3
```

The problem is with the termination condition of your loop:

```
while(ptr1!=ptr5->next)
```

`ptr5` is the last element of the original linked list (e.g. node `3`), and you are trying to terminate your loop when you have iterated through each element (get past node `3`).  However, if the last element is an odd number, it will be moved to the end of the list, and `ptr1` will never actually "get past ptr5".  Instead, it will only catch up to it, move it, and then keep iterating through the odd numbers of the list over and over.

I made some minor edits to your program to fix the problem, although your algorithm is still overly complicated and you should think about simpler ways of solving the same problem:

```
void segregate(struct Node**head_ref)
{   int len=0,count=0;
    struct Node* ptr1=*head_ref;
    struct Node* ptr2=*head_ref;
    struct Node* prev=NULL;
    while(ptr2->next!=NULL)
    {
        if((ptr2->data)%2==0) count++;
        ptr2=ptr2->next;
        len++;
    }
    if(ptr2->data%2==0)  count++;
    if(count==len+1||count==0)  return;
    struct Node* ptr5=ptr2;
    while(ptr1!=ptr5->next)
    {
        if((ptr1->data%2)==0)
        { if(flag==0) {
        *head_ref=ptr1;
        flag=1;}
            prev=ptr1;
            // I added this termination condition
            if (ptr1 == ptr5)
                break;
            ptr1=ptr1->next;
        }
        else
        {
          if(prev!=NULL)  prev->next=ptr1->next;
            ptr2->next=ptr1;
            ptr2=ptr2->next;
            // I added this termination condition
            if (ptr1 == ptr5) {
                ptr2->next=NULL;
                break;
            }
            ptr1=ptr1->next;
            ptr2->next=NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example of a simpler solution

This solution assumes that you actually need to create a new sorted list instead of just printing out the answer.  It iterates through the original list and places each element into one of two lists.  Then it joins the two lists and returns the joined list.

```
void segregate(struct Node**head_ref)
{
    struct Node *evenList = NULL;
    struct Node *evenTail = NULL;
    struct Node *oddList  = NULL;
    struct Node *oddTail  = NULL;

    // Separate nodes into two lists.
    for (struct Node *p = *head_ref; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
        if ((p->data) % 2 == 0) {
            if (evenTail != NULL)
                evenTail->next = p;
            else
                evenList = p;
            evenTail = p;
        } else {
            if (oddTail != NULL)
                oddTail->next = p;
            else
                oddList = p;
            oddTail = p;
        }
    }

    // Terminate odd list with NULL.
    if (oddList != NULL)
        oddTail->next = NULL;
    // Place odd list at the end of the even list.
    if (evenList != NULL)
        evenTail->next = oddList;
    else
        evenList = oddList;

    *head_ref = evenList;
}
```